# Using many element ids on a html page advisable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I would like to consider a case that i have an html page and I would want to parse element's information using javascript and using it for #googleanalytics tracking

However I have a concern is it better to have element id's specified for each area of an html page for parsing through javascript/jquery? Is it advisable? Does it has any impact on page load time?

Example : I have an page where I have around 6-8 (may be more) areas to be populated with certain information and use such information to be tracked in google analytics based on user's interaction i.e. user clicked on a particular area

Please let me know your suggestions. And if I need to provide more information. Thanks

Comment: What is the exact question here?

Comment: Is it better to have element ids.. -> better than what?

Comment: It's better to delegate the event further up to an ancestor and check which element it came from. This way you only have one event handler instead of 6-8.

Comment: @epascarello using element ids over not using them what's better?

Comment: @MichalKlouda refer above comment. Thanks

Comment: You want to know what the downside of adding a few extra bytes to the page is?

Comment: @epascarello Yes sure. It would help me to decide what I am losing if I use element Ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downside is you're adding characters to your html.

The upside is it makes whatever code you write much easier to maintain.  In the end it'll likely decrease the size of the page overall, as instead of having to do gnarly DOM traversal contortions, you have `document.getElementById` doing all of that for you.  Also `document.getElementById` is fast.

Use IDs.  Just don't repeat them.